# chef-solo: Handler trying to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8889/nodes/

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I am trying to test one of my cookbook on test-kitchen node. After successful converge or chef-client, the chef handler throws errors connecting to some server. I think it wants to send the node details to a chef-server.

I don't know what to do? Do I have to set this host somewhere or is there a way to disable this.

.kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
 name: vagrant

provisioner:
name: chef_solo
require_chef_omnibus: '12.4.3'
```

Chef Log:

```
   Running handlers:
   [2017-01-05T20:46:54-06:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8889/nodes/client-service-redhat-66, retry 1/5
   [2017-01-05T20:46:59-06:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8889/nodes/client-service-redhat-66, retry 2/5
   [2017-01-05T20:47:04-06:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8889/nodes/client-service-redhat-66, retry 3/5
   [2017-01-05T20:47:09-06:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8889/nodes/client-service-redhat-66, retry 4/5
```

Comment: How do you run converge ? Do you have chef server installed ?

Comment: @YuriyZhigulskiy I run `kitchen converge` and I don't have chef server locally

Comment: could you add more logs of a run with `log_level: debug` added for the provisionner ? I feel SO is not the right place for this, probably better  on https://discourse.chef.io or on slack.

Comment: Your test kitchen might be too old, what version do you have?

Comment: @coderanger It's running on latest `bundle show test-kitchen` =>
`/Users/jim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/test-kitchen-1.14.2`